# Can I change Facebook apprequests message in unity-facebook-sdk?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to send a invite to my friends who doesn't use my app in facebook, so, I used FB.apprequets function to do. My design is to show the recipient {my custom message}. But request that the recipient received is always "GAME NAME: FRIEND NAME sent you a request".

Is there ways to change that message?

Also in Facebook reference, they say "If a recipient didn't install the game, he will receive invite message like Anita invited you to play Friend Smash!". But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A custom message is not shown in the notification jewel.

It will only show up if the user views their notifications under https://www.facebook.com/games/activity

This is by design, and nothing you can change.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i was wondering if you got the invite to work? Because currently right now my game sends app requests, but only to people who have installed my game can see the app invite/request in the notifications panel. Other than that, they can't see the app request if they have never installed the game.